# I have no SUDO rights, yet I want to install and run RoR. How can I do it?

Tags: command-line, apt, ppa

When I insert the following command:
**sudo add-apt-repository ppa:aapo-rantalainen/rigsofrods**
it asks for my password, and then says this, which is like same on every command I issue:
**Sorry, user mike is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/add-apt-repository ppa:aapo-rantalainen/rigsofrods' as root on Satellite**
How can I bypass the terminal during installation?

Comment: There is no way around it if you have not sudo permissions because that command needs it. I suggest that you ask the system administrator to install the PPA (and the tool that you want to install from it) for you. - But I notice that the PPA is deprecated - The newest version is from 2012 (nine years ago!) and might not work in current versions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not have permission to install software, then please ask your system administrator to do so. Alternatively, ask your system administrator to add you to the `sudo`  group so you can perform system administrative tasks yourself.

Rigs of Rods may be installed and run as user by downloading the zip file of the [Portable edition](https://www.rigsofrods.org/download). After download, the program folder can be moved to a convenient location. Within the folder, there is a script RunRoR.  `cd`  into that folder and start the program with the command `./RunRoR` after

Comment: But is there a way to add the PPA manually and then install RoR without CMD?

Comment: I did some research for you and added how to install the portable version. Tested it myself.

Comment: YES! THANK YOU! IT WORKED!